# SQL (Oracle) to query for record with max date, only if the end_dt has a value

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, max

I am trying to select a record from a row by looking at both the start date and the end date. What I need to do is pick the max start date, then only return a result from that max date if the end date has a value.

I hope the images below help clarify this a bit more. This is in Oracle based SQL.

[image]

Example #2

[image]

I can, so far, either return all the records or incorrectly return a record in scenario #2 but I've yet to figure out the best way to make this work. I would *greatly* appreciate any assistance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an analytic function:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 1 grp_id, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') st_dt, to_date('23/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ed_dt from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 1 grp_id, to_date('24/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') st_dt, to_date('15/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ed_dt from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 1 grp_id, to_date('17/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') st_dt, to_date('30/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ed_dt from dual union all
                     select 4 id, 2 grp_id, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') st_dt, to_date('17/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ed_dt from dual union all
                     select 5 id, 2 grp_id, to_date('21/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') st_dt, to_date('23/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ed_dt from dual union all
                     select 6 id, 2 grp_id, to_date('14/04/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') st_dt, to_date('16/05/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ed_dt from dual union all
                     select 7 id, 2 grp_id, to_date('28/05/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') st_dt, null ed_dt from dual),
             res as (select id,
                            grp_id,
                            st_dt,
                            ed_dt,
                            max(st_dt) over (partition by grp_id) max_st_dt
                     from   sample_data)
select id,
       grp_id,
       st_dt,
       ed_dt
from   res
where  st_dt = max_st_dt
and    ed_dt is not null;


        ID     GRP_ID ST_DT      ED_DT     
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3          1 17/03/2015 30/03/2015
```

Comment: The scenario that it does not work with is when the max date is null .. in that situation (grp 2) it should not return anything. In this situation it's giving back the second highest date.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood the requirement. Will have to look at this tomorrow when I'm back in work, but it's simple enough to fix - take the case statement out of the analytic function that gets the max_start_date, and then add a "and ed_dt is not null" to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one of the simplest way.

```
select * from
(
select apay_id,
       max(start_dt) OVER () max_start_dt,
        start_dt,
       end_dt
from sample
)
where
start_dt=max_start_dt
and end_dt is not null
```

Idea is to get maximum start_dt and corresponding end_dt.
And then filter result if end_dt is null.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9da0/1)

**Database Schema**

```
create table sample
(apay_id number(7),
 account_number number(7),
 start_dt date,
 end_dt date);
```

**Sample1**

```
 insert into sample values(554433, 123456, '15-Aug-15', null);
 insert into sample values(112266, 123456, '21-Jul-15', '31-Aug-15');
 insert into sample values(733221, 123456, '29-Jun-15', '31-Jul-15');
```

**Output for Sample1**

```
No rows
```

**Sample2**

```
 insert into sample values(554433, 123456, '15-Aug-15', '11-Nov-15');
 insert into sample values(112266, 123456, '21-Jul-15', '31-Aug-15');
 insert into sample values(733221, 123456, '29-Jun-15', '31-Jul-15');
```

**Output for Sample2**

```
| APAY_ID |             MAX_START_DT |                     END_DT |
|---------|--------------------------|----------------------------|
|  554433 | August, 15 2015 00:00:00 | November, 11 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: It only seems to work if the null record is first. I moved the null to the end and it returned a value when it should not have.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35b68/1

Comment: Corrected the solution

Answer (score 0):

select * from ( select apay_id from sample where end_dt is not null order by start_dt desc) where rownum=1

I think this can also work.